# Mark link's target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML file containing this:

```
<span id="id1"> text 1</span>
<span id="id2"> text 2</span>
<span id="id3"> text 3</span>
<a class="mark" href="#id1">mark text 1</a> 
<a class="mark" href="#id2">mark text 2</a> 
<a class="mark" href="#id3">mark text 3</a>
```

If I click one of the  `<a>`'s I want the corresponding span change its text color to red, and set all other  text color back to black, as they were, so only the last clicked link makes its destination show up red.

Is this the way to do this:

```
$("a.mark").on('click', function(e) {
    $("a.mark").attr( 'href').css('color', 'black') ;
    $(this).attr('href').css( 'color', 'red') ; 
    }
);
```

Comment: This can all be done in CSS with the `:target` selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in css selector `:target` which will accomplish what you are trying to do with javascript.

http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

```
span:target{color:red}
```

`:target` will select whatever ID is specified by the hash in the url, so: /index.html#span1 targets the id span1

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/eGMqh/

**HTML:**

```
<span id="id1"> text 1</span>

<span id="id2"> text 2</span>

<span id="id3"> text 3</span>

<a class="mark" href="#id1">mark text 1</a> 
<a class="mark" href="#id2">mark text 2</a> 
<a class="mark" href="#id3">mark text 3</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("a.mark").on('click', function (e) {
        $("span").css("color", "black");
        $($(this).attr("href")).css('color', 'red');
    });

});
```

Comment: What if there are other, uninvolved, `span`s in the page? They'll be set to `color: black` as well.

Comment: Indeed, but I could just give the relevant spans a class.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Close, just remove `.attr('href')`:</strike>

```
$("a.mark").on('click', function (e) {
    $("a.mark").css('color', 'black');
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sUGGK/)**

If you want the span color to change, use:

```
$("a.mark").on('click', function (e) {
    $("span").css('color', 'black');
    $($(this).attr('href')).css('color', 'red');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZEajX/)**

Answer (score 0):

Close.

```
$("a.mark").on('click', function(e) {
  $("a.mark").each(
    function() {
      $($(this).attr('href')).css('color', 'black') ;
    }
  );

  $($(this).attr('href')).css( 'color', 'red') ; 
});
```

We pull the `href` off of each `a.mark`, and then retrieve that element, setting its color to black (consider using classes instead of direct color styles, BTW).

Then, we grab the `href` attribute of *just* the clicked element, and set *that* element's color to `red`.

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/GhsJv

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

This worked for me...

```
$("a.mark").on('click', function(e) {
    $("a.mark").css('color', 'black') ;
    $(this).css( 'color', 'red') ; 
    }
);
```